# Mechanism of the Synthesis of Cyclooctatetraene from Pseudopelletierine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

We've been looking at total synthesis in class and the uses of the products. An example was Willstätter's use of pseudopelletierine to synthesise cyclooctatetraene.

[image]

I've just been wondering how the mechanism would proceed and if someone could show me the entire reaction scheme then that would be great.

I think the first step to the mechanism involves a sodium radical attacking the ketone. I'm just a bit intrigued how it would all work.

Comment: Are you looking for the mechanism of the step involving sodium? or of the entire sequence?

Comment: The entire sequence would be really helofull, thanks :)

Comment: I also think there will be intermediate radical in first reaction. BTW it's old and rather primitive synthesis

Comment: http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/bouveault-blanc-reduction.shtm